# Lazy Column won't scroll

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 32.dp)
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
      SomeHeader()
      Results()
      SomeOtherComposable()
    }
```

Results looks like

```
ListOfResults()
```

And the list of results is

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = modifier
        .padding(top = 16.dp)
        .fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),

    ) {
    items(items = results, key = { it.id }) { result ->
        ResultItem(result = result)
      }
```

So, the problem is when I want to scroll the Results() I can't scroll them. I've tried with the rememberScrollState and similar stuff and that's not working.

Comment: Something else seems to be the problem, this code should work, also you may wants to pass the `Modifier.weight(1)` to the `ListOfResults()` as `fillMaxSize` will take all the space available, and I doubt your `SomeOtherComposable()` is not visible

Comment: like this `ListOfResults(Modifier.weight(1F))` `fun ListOfResults(modifier: Modifier) { }` can explain if needed,
Also please share more code, and check the Modifier of the parent composable and other two child components

Comment: Already tried that and it is not working.

Comment: Then please share more code